# Await nested forEach behaviour

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why does this snippet

```
const firstArray = ['toto', 'toto'];
const secondArray = ['titi', 'titi'];
firstArray.forEach(async (toto, i) =>
{
  await secondArray.forEach(async titi =>
  {
    // async code
    console.log(titi, i);
  });
  // async code
  console.log(toto, i);
});
```

produce the following output:

[image: output]

Removing the `await` keyword produces the expected output

[image]

My guess is it resides in the `await` keyword's behaviour, as, without which, the produced output is the expected output.

EDIT: this is a purely trivial question. I want to understand why using await before a forEach provides this behaviour. There is no 'concrete code' behind this.

EDIT2: edited the snippet as the comments and answer reflected misunderstanding of my question

Comment: I get `titi titi titi titi toto toto` from your snippet and the other version if I move the first await to the second `console.log`, I may be missing something though?

Comment: But `await`-ing the returned value of `forEach` does not make sense anyway, as `await` is made to receive a `Promise`, so that your code looks synchronous while being asynchronous, but `forEach` returns `undefined`. This does not explain why your snippet behaves the way you say though.

Comment: You should post all your code

Comment: @JoshRumbut We get the same output. Might edit the question to make it clearer. The first await isn't to be moved, it is to be removed

Comment: I was just playing around when I noticed this, it isn't actually needed either @sp00m

Comment: there is no promise that resolves later in time in your code so there is nothing to `await`

Comment: When using async/await it's better to stay in the same scope so a foo...of loop is better then forEach

Comment: I usually avoid doing this, hence my surprise @Endless

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 5):

forEach works synchronously meaning it doesn't do anything with the return of each iteration (in this case, the promise) and it ignores it.

If you use instead:

```
for(let item of arrayItems)
```

or a normal for loop you should see the expected result working asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to await all promises before continuing. If should be the case, a combination of `Array.prototype.reduce(...)`, `Array.prototype.map(...)` and `Promise.all(...)` will better suit:

```js
const allPromises = firstArray.reduce((accumulatedPromises, toto) => {
  const secondArrayPromises = secondArray.map((titi) => {
    return // some promise;
  });
  const firstArrayPromise = // some promise;
  return accumulatedPromises.concat(secondArrayPromises, firstArrayPromise);
}, []);
const finalPromise = Promise.all(allPromises);
```

Then, either `await finalPromise` if you're within an `async function`, or use `.then(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your outer `forEach` loop spits out two functions (note the `async` type you have; async functions automatically return a Promise) directly on the stack that then runs in sequence before finally outputting from the `firstArray`. So after both the functions are executed your output for the outer loop is printed. This is how the `forEach` loop works with `async` functions.

To use `async/await` with loops, you would want to have:

```
async function boot() {
  for(let item of list) {
    await getData(); // Here getData returns a promise
  }
}

boot();
```

Another way could be to use [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) for `Promise`:

```
let exec = [];
await Promise.map(list => getData());
// Here Promise.map iterates over list
// and returns a list of promises which are 
// then resolved using await
```

Answer (score -1):

The key to understanding is that `await` is asynchronous. So everything after will be executed no earlier than the current execution thread returns. Thus, the part

```
// async code
console.log(toto);
```

is put to a queue rather than being executed immediately.

Async/await essentially wraps your code like this:

```js
const firstArray = ['toto', 'toto'];
const secondArray = ['titi', 'titi'];
firstArray.forEach((toto,i) => new Promise((resolve)=>
{
  resolve((new Promise((resolve)=>resolve(secondArray.forEach(titi => new Promise((resolve)=>
  {
    resolve(console.log(titi, i));
  }))))).then(()=>console.log(toto,i))
);}));
```

Now consider this code as well (`setTimeout` is pretty much a promise that is resolved after a given amount of time):

```js
const firstArray = ['toto', 'toto'];
const secondArray = ['titi', 'titi'];
firstArray.forEach((toto, i) =>
{
  secondArray.forEach(titi =>
  {
    console.log(titi, i);
  });
  setTimeout(()=>console.log(toto, i));
});
```